# which google map plugin used cordova ionic framwork within ion-view

Tags: google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-android-api-2

What is the best plugin to display google map on cordova? withh ionic framework within the ion-view tag.

I am trying google map plugin but no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo location plugin will not help you display map its just for only finding long & lat based on current your location.

I you want display map, try this plugin https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

Or it can be possible without plugin also please follow below link

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

If you want sample Ionic Google map try following command

ionic start myApp maps

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-maps

Comment: Issue solved however i can only load map on default opened tab but not other tabs. nothing will show up on other tabs.

Comment: Can you give some code sample or Pseudo code? Which plugin you are using?

Comment: @davidlee If this answer helps you, then please accept the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use **Geolocation**

enter the following line in your cmd to add this plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

Comment: This plugin is for fetching longitude and latitude of your current location not for display map.